# Cypher Query in Neo4j to ORDER BY some data

Tags: sorting, neo4j, cypher

I got a spring application with a query that looks like that.

```
MATCH (d:Drug) WHERE toLower(d.tradingName) CONTAINS toLower({0}) OR toLower(d.expire) CONTAINS 
toLower({0}) RETURN (d)-[]-() ORDER BY d.expire
```

d.expire is a string in my pojos so the query i posted sorts everyting alphabetical. Thats not what i want.

How is it possible to parse d.expire as a date and order the results as Dates ?

Comment: please share an example value of d.expire

Comment: @TheTeacher 

"expire": "2018-04-10T10:59:01.000Z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MATCH (d:Drug) 
WHERE toLower(d.tradingName) CONTAINS toLower({0}) OR toLower(d.expire) CONTAINS 
toLower({0}) 
WITH d , datetime(d.expire) as expiryDate
RETURN (d)-[]-() ORDER BY expiryDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a slight improvement on @TheTeacher's fine answer.

The `=~` operator can be used with a regular expression to perform [case-insensitive comparisons](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/where/#case-insensitive-regular-expressions). Also, `WITH` the clause is not needed.

```
WITH "(?i).*" + {0} + ".*" AS regex
MATCH (d:Drug)
WHERE d.tradingName =~ regex OR d.expire =~ regex
RETURN (d)--() ORDER BY datetime(d.expire)
```